# Connection Strings For SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I could not create a `.mdf` file for `ProjectsContext`.

The default `.mdf` is created but the other one not ...why ?

What am I doing wrong?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=user-Pc\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf"  
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ProjectsDB" 
         connectionString="Data Source=user-PC\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=ProjectsDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ProjectsDB.mdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My context :

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext() : base("ProjectsDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ProjectEntry> Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Requiernments> RequiernmentEntries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you hit the ProjectContext DB?  You need to either run a migration on the database or initiate a query to that database for it to be created in entity framework.  At least that has been my experience.

Comment: oky :) I did update-database -Force and it created ... can you post your previous answer again it help me to have the 2 context into one database! ..

Comment: I meant the previous  other  answer ....the connection string ?!!i need it please